# Adjust values as auto_increment from 1 for innodb tables after deleting some auto_incremented columns

Tags: mysql

I have one abc  table with ID column(PK,Auto_increment) and values 1 to 10.I deleted the 5th and 6th record.Now the ID column is like 1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10.I want ID column as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8..How to do this?I tried

alter table abc auto_increment = 1;

and
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE abc  SET  taskruns.`ID` = @count:= @count + 1   WHERE ID=1;

But its not working.My table is innodb.

Comment: Why the `WHERE ID=1` ?

Comment: Without where ID the update is not working.I have created one SP for this.

Comment: There's no need to change the auto_increment of the table in advance, because you do not want to change the automatic process, but to assign different values manually. It would be helpful if you posted the error. But before doing so, try a `ORDER BY ID` instead the `WHERE ID=1`.

Comment: It is returning a error 1175 (update without where condition ).And if I am giving order by how the values adjusted as 1...8 ?I want the ID column as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...(I am getting 1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10)

Comment: The order by tells MySQL in which order to update the rows. And the @count variable in your code sets them to 1, 2, 3, ... it's incremented by 1 with every `UPDATE`.